# Azure Service Busのタイムアウトについて

Tags: node.js, azure

Azure Service Busについて、node.jsのSDKを利用しておりますが、

sendQueueMessage「 connect ETIMEDOUT 」が発生します。

タイムアウト時間を延ばしたいのですが、どこで設定すればよろしいのでしょうか。

また、上記エラーが発生する場合、最大同時接続数なども関係ありますでしょうか。

何か情報がございましたら、ご提供おねがいします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

node.jsのSDKではTimeoutを設定できないようでした。